Is there a web interface for managing users and tablespaces in oracle 19c
I just installed Oracle 19c on Red Hat and would like a graphical way of managing users and tablespaces. I enabled EM Express but the new interface (omx) does not allow to manage users, and the old (emx) interface cannot be used because Flash is forbidden by our policy. I also discarded SQL Developer since it is too complex: I would like a simpler tool. Does oracle database include anything similar to the EM Database Control of oracle 10g?

Not really. SQL Developer is probably your best bet for GUI unless you want to use the SQLcl or SQL Plus command line.

Thank you, @pmdba . That's probably the reason why SQL Server gained market share: oracle database isn't provided with a decent administration client. Too sad.

Most people use SQL Developer without issue. It isn't perfect, but it's free. I used that, and TOAD for years.
